# How does Andriod .so files Reverse Engineering with a dissasembler like IDA pro and Cutter work

Tags: ida, apk

So few days ago going through youtube Reverse Engineering videos, i came across a particular video where an android application was modified using IDA pro by disassembling it's .so file found in /lib directory in every android app.

This is the link to the video
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=m-t-jFBy7FE

I was further curious as i have never seen anyone modify an android App from the .so file usually when we talk of reversing android apps we use tools like Apktool, Dex2jar, jd-gui and so on.

What kind of Reverse Engineering is this and what exactly is going on???

Someone please shed some light on this topic. i've been confused for days.

Comment: please note that .so files is a shared objects. usually it is a binary from cpp. in some apps use it to hide their core functionality.

Comment: A related question: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4624/how-do-i-reverse-engineer-so-files-found-in-android-apks