# How to reverse android native libraries? Best resources?

Tags: android

I want to improve myself in Android penetration testing. For this task i need to learn reversing the native libraries of an APK file to detect vulnerabilities. What is the best way and resources for my task?

Comment: Besides some of the Java/Android specific glue, reverse engineering native libraries is no different than "regular" reverse engineering.

Comment: @multithr3at3d What happens when actual form compiled for arm cpu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reverse engineer .so files found in android APKs?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4624/how-do-i-reverse-engineer-so-files-found-in-android-apks)